# vb.net datagridview inserting instead of updating

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

Ok. Tough explanation but here we go. 
I have a 2 part project. The first application/part inserts data into a SQL db. This works fine. The second user application pulls that same data via a datagridview. The user needs to update the last four columns and save. This works most of the time. Intermittently, in the SQL database, the last 4 columns have information, but the data in the other columns (that was there previously from the first application) is gone. 
I ran the SQL profiler to catch the statements coming into SQL.

The functioning statement is an "update" and the other is an "insert" which I'm sure is a "new" table, but the row unique identifier is used and already exists. sp I am not sure it is actually creating a new row as much as it is writing over the existing. I don't understand why the DGV would switch between inserts/updates. It should always be an update in my application. I don't even have an add or delete function set up in the binding nav.

This is a GOOD SQL insert:

EXEC **Sp_executesql**

N'***UPDATE*** [dbo].[ProductionDownTimeTable] SET [LineID] = @LineID, [Shift] = @Shift, [DTMinShiftTotal] = @DTMinShiftTotal, [DTInstance] = @DTInstance, [ProductionUpDateTime] = @ProductionUpDateTime, [DTEventMin] = @DTEventMin, [DTEventSec] = @DTEventSec, [DTEventReason] = @DTEventReason, [DTEventReasonDetails] = @DTEventReasonDetails, [DTReasonDateTime] = @DTReasonDateTime, [DTReasonBadgeNo] = @DTReasonBadgeNo WHERE (([ID] = @Original_ID) AND ((@IsNull_LineID = 1 AND [LineID] IS NULL) OR ([LineID] = @Original_LineID)) AND ((@IsNull_Shift = 1 AND [Shift] IS NULL) OR ([Shift] = @Original_Shift)) AND ((@IsNull_DTMinShiftTotal = 1 AND [DTMinShiftTotal] IS NULL) OR ([DTMinShiftTotal] = @Original_DTMinShiftTotal)) AND ((@IsNull_DTInstance = 1 AND [DTInstance] IS NULL) OR ([DTInstance] = @Original_DTInstance)) AND ((@IsNull_ProductionUpDateTime = 1 AND [ProductionUpDateTime] IS NULL) OR ([ProductionUpDateTime] = @Original_ProductionUpDateTime)) AND ((@IsNull_DTEventMin = 1 AND [DTEventMin] IS NULL) OR ([DTEventMin] = @Original_DTEventMin)) AND ((@IsNull_DTEventSec = 1 AND [DTEventSec] IS NULL) OR ([DTEventSec] = @Original_DTEventSec)) AND ((@IsNull_DTEventReason = 1 AND [DTEventReason] IS NULL) OR ([DTEventReason] = @Original_DTEventReason)) AND ((@IsNull_DTEventReasonDetails = 1 AND [DTEventReasonDetails] IS NULL) OR ([DTEventReasonDetails] = @Original_DTEventReasonDetails)) AND ((@IsNull_DTReasonDateTime = 1 AND [DTReasonDateTime] IS NULL) OR ([DTReasonDateTime] = @Original_DTReasonDateTime)) AND ((@IsNull_DTReasonBadgeNo = 1 AND [DTReasonBadgeNo] IS NULL) OR ([DTReasonBadgeNo] = @Original_DTReasonBadgeNo)));

SELECT ID, LineID, Shift, DTMinShiftTotal, DTInstance, ProductionUpDateTime, DTEventMin, DTEventSec, DTEventReason, DTEventReasonDetails, DTReasonDateTime, DTReasonBadgeNo FROM ProductionDownTimeTable WHERE (ID = @ID)'

,

N'@LineID varchar(2),@Shift int,@DTMinShiftTotal int,@DTInstance int,@ProductionUpDateTime datetime,@DTEventMin int,@DTEventSec int,@DTEventReason varchar(8),@DTEventReasonDetails varchar(8000),@DTReasonDateTime datetime,@DTReasonBadgeNo int,@Original_ID int,@IsNull_LineID int,@Original_LineID varchar(2),@IsNull_Shift int,@Original_Shift int,@IsNull_DTMinShiftTotal int,@Original_DTMinShiftTotal int,@IsNull_DTInstance int,@Original_DTInstance int,@IsNull_ProductionUpDateTime int,@Original_ProductionUpDateTime datetime,@IsNull_DTEventMin int,@Original_DTEventMin int,@IsNull_DTEventSec int,@Original_DTEventSec int,@IsNull_DTEventReason int,@Original_DTEventReason varchar(8000),@IsNull_DTEventReasonDetails int,@Original_DTEventReasonDetails varchar(8000),@IsNull_DTReasonDateTime int,@Original_DTReasonDateTime datetime,@IsNull_DTReasonBadgeNo int,@Original_DTReasonBadgeNo int,@ID int'

,

@LineID='1S',

@Shift=2,

@DTMinShiftTotal=17,

@DTInstance=6,

@ProductionUpDateTime='2016-05-09 19:07:52',

@DTEventMin=4,

@DTEventSec=30,

@DTEventReason='ENG TEST',

@DTEventReasonDetails=NULL,

@DTReasonDateTime='2016-05-10 12:16:20.157',

@DTReasonBadgeNo=1234,

@Original_ID=679,

@IsNull_LineID=0,

@Original_LineID='1S',

@IsNull_Shift=0,

@Original_Shift=2,

@IsNull_DTMinShiftTotal=0,

@Original_DTMinShiftTotal=17,

@IsNull_DTInstance=0,

@Original_DTInstance=6,

@IsNull_ProductionUpDateTime=0,

@Original_ProductionUpDateTime='2016-05-09 19:07:52',

@IsNull_DTEventMin=0,

@Original_DTEventMin=4,

@IsNull_DTEventSec=0,

@Original_DTEventSec=30,

@IsNull_DTEventReason=1,

@Original_DTEventReason=NULL,

@IsNull_DTEventReasonDetails=1,

@Original_DTEventReasonDetails=NULL,

@IsNull_DTReasonDateTime=1,

@Original_DTReasonDateTime=NULL,

@IsNull_DTReasonBadgeNo=1,

@Original_DTReasonBadgeNo=NULL,

@ID=679

This one is missing all but the last 4 columns:

EXEC **Sp_executesql**

N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductionDownTimeTable] ([LineID], [Shift], [DTMinShiftTotal], [DTInstance], [ProductionUpDateTime], [DTEventMin], [DTEventSec], [DTEventReason], [DTEventReasonDetails], [DTReasonDateTime], [DTReasonBadgeNo]) VALUES (@LineID, @Shift, @DTMinShiftTotal, @DTInstance, @ProductionUpDateTime, @DTEventMin, @DTEventSec, @DTEventReason, @DTEventReasonDetails, @DTReasonDateTime, @DTReasonBadgeNo);

SELECT ID, LineID, Shift, DTMinShiftTotal, DTInstance, ProductionUpDateTime, DTEventMin, DTEventSec, DTEventReason, DTEventReasonDetails, DTReasonDateTime, DTReasonBadgeNo FROM ProductionDownTimeTable WHERE (ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY())'

,

N'@LineID varchar(8000),@Shift int,@DTMinShiftTotal int,@DTInstance int,@ProductionUpDateTime datetime,@DTEventMin int,@DTEventSec int,@DTEventReason varchar(17),@DTEventReasonDetails varchar(15),@DTReasonDateTime datetime,@DTReasonBadgeNo int'

,

@LineID=NULL,

@Shift=NULL,

@DTMinShiftTotal=NULL,

@DTInstance=NULL,

@ProductionUpDateTime=NULL,

@DTEventMin=NULL,

@DTEventSec=NULL,

@DTEventReason='STILE/BACKER LINE',

@DTEventReasonDetails='face clinch out',

@DTReasonDateTime='2016-05-10 13:22:42.790',

@DTReasonBadgeNo=6

This is my binding navigator code:

```
 Private Sub ProductionDownTimeTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProductionDownTimeTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        'DataGridView-Binding Navigtor Save Button 
        Try

            Me.Validate()
            Me.ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ProductionDownTimeDataSet1)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Being that this is my first project, I am not sure where to go from here. 
I am thinking that I am missing something in the B-Nav save code.

Please let me know what you think.

Thank you.

Comment: Please take some time to edit your question so that the code is more readable. You can select a block of code and use ctrl-K to format it as code. SQL formatters are available if you search for them - they might help.

Comment: Andrew Morton, I hope that is better. Thanks. I learned something new.

Comment: If that second one is supposed to be updating existing data, it's not. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but anything with scope_identity is also something that I'd look at, especially with no transaction.

Comment: Nikki9696, The SQL statement was created in VB automatically during the binding of the datagridview. Do to the variable values missing, it cleared the existing data. It did however update the last 4 columns. I see that the previous one states "ID=@ID" interesting. Thanks